# Formula to find the second to last value in row - Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have the formula to find the last value in a row - =LOOKUP(1,1/(3:3>0),3:3) (depending on the row)

but can't seem to get it to return the second to last value/cell in the row.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=INDEX(3:3, AGGREGATE(14, 6, COLUMN(A:XFC)/(A3:XFC3>0), 2))
```

Comment: Thank you! That did return a value. But my columns right now range from A:BM, and will be continuing to insert more columns... so I will need the formula to automatically update the range. Could you also explain the 14 and 6?

Comment: That's now coming up as 


=INDEX(3:3, AGGREGATE(14, 6, COLUMN($1:$1048576)/(3:3>0), 2))

returning a 0 :(

Answer (score 0):

Awesome.. I edited the formula to:

```
=INDEX(3:3, AGGREGATE(14, 6, COLUMN(A3:XFC3)/(A3:BL3>0), 2))
```

Where BL3 is where my current last data value ends. Once I drag, the formula automatically updated the column and row value.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

For row #3, the **array formula**:

```
=INDEX(3:3,IF(COUNTA(3:3)=0,"",MAX((3:3<>"")*(COLUMN(3:3))))-1)
```

will yield the next-to-last value in that row:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

If you are sure that row #3 will not be empty, then use this array formula instead:

```
=INDEX(3:3,MAX((3:3<>"")*(COLUMN(3:3)))-1)
```

To avoid array formulas consider:

```
=INDEX(3:3,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((COLUMN(3:3))*(3:3<>"")))-1)
```

Comment: Both formulas - I did enter correctly - returned a 0

Comment: @AmyCollins  Then use **Jeeped's** approach.